# How to add setting section in custom post type

Tags: plugin-development

can any one guide me how can I add setting section in custom post type for each new post. something like in the image. 
Note. without using any Plugin. thanks.[image]

Comment: you can try that https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) (ACF) is a way to go. The plugin offers plenty of fields, conditions, and the documentation is top-notch.

For your specific needs you might want to use the [Tab](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tab/) field with left aligned positioning, and limit the display of this field to your custom post type. It is ridiculously easy.